# angular2 http.get not working with webpack-server proxy

Tags: angular, proxy, webpack

This is my webpack-server config

```
       devServer:{
        proxy: {
            '/open/*': {
                target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
            }
        },
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
```

and route code is here, just same as the doc code of angular2

```
const routes:RouterConfig = [
{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: 'login',
    component: loginComponent
},
```

and i start the server no error

```
70% 3/3 build moduleshttp://localhost:9000/
webpack result is served from http://localhost:9000/
content is served from /Users/atyun/code/weinei-web
404s will fallback to /index.html
```

my html code

```
<button type="button" (click)="hello()">hello</button>
```

this is a angular2 event button

and the function code

```
hello() {
        this.http.get("/open/v1").map(data=>data).subscribe(response=>console.log(response))
    }
```

and I open the browser, when I click the button, the page will reload, why? Browser console has error but I can't see it because it reloads so fast.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you are using Chrome, check the checkbox in the console `Preserve log`. And post the error

Comment: error is   cannot proxy to http://127.0.0.1:3000 (connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000)

Comment: Are you using angular-cli for your project ? And are you using any proxy in your computer ?

Comment: @pdfarhad i used webpack server plugin and none proxy ; i even reboot my system .its worked in my own macbook pro ;but not work in my mac mini.

Comment: using Subscribe in a button click, results to large number of calls - Keep a fiddler on, you would see list of APIs requested.